# With Tkinter trying to open a text file in Text() widget

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog

Guys i was trying to open a text file in Text() widget.The problem is when i click Open File,i get the file dialog,and when i select a file and click open,i get TypeError.Please advise.Thank you.
This is the relevant code

```
open = PhotoImage(file='ico/open.gif')
filemenu.add_command(label="Open",accelerator='Ctrl + O',compound='left',image=open,command=open_file)
file_name = None

def open_file(event=None):
    input_file_name = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt",filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"), ("Text Documents", "*.txt")])
    if input_file_name:
        global file_name
        file_name = input_file_name
        root.title('{} - {}'.format(os.path.basename(file_name), PROGRAM_NAME))
        content.delete(1.0, END)
        with open(file_name) as _file:
            content.insert(1.0, _file.read())
```

And i get this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Crystal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__

    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Crystal\Desktop\New folder\text_ed\ui.py", line 61, in open_file
    with open(file_name) as _file:
TypeError: 'PhotoImage' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you the problem. You've replaced the built-in `open` statement with an image. Name your image something else.

Comment: God damn...I'll kill my self....I changed the name of the image and the name of the var that holds Photoimage and it works.Maaaaaany Thanks :)